# Parse files to obtain array of arrays in matlab

Tags: file, matlab, parsing

I need to parse a .txt file in Matlab so that all lines of the file are a different element in an array. Each element of the array would also be an array of integers. So I need to make an array of arrays from a .txt file.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out which function to use to parse the file. If I use importdata(filename), it only parses the first line of the file. If I use textscan, it parses the file in colums, and the file is formatted like:

```
1 1 1 1 1
13 13 13 13 13

2 2 2 2 2
14 14 14 14 14
```

I need each of the rows to be an array that I can then use to compare my data against.

Is there an option for either one of those functions that would work for my purposes? I've tried looking on the MATLAB documentation, but can't make sense of it.

Comment: Are the arrays all going to be the same length, or all different lengths?

Comment: @Chris Taylor I'd prefer if they'd be able to be different. The first line needs to be 5, then the immediate line after needs to be 1. So it would be [1 1 1 1 1] then [13] then [2 2 2 2 2] then [14]. But if that's not possible, they can all be length of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each array needs to be a different size, you need to use a cell array to contain them. Something like this:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt'); %opens the file
tline = fgets(fid); % reads in the first line
data = {}; % creates an empty cell array
index = 1; % initializes index
while ischar(tline) % loops while the line that has just been read contains characters, that is, the end of the file has not been reached.  
    data{index} = str2num(tline); % converts the line that has just been read in to a string and assigns it to the current column of data
    tline = fgets(fid); % reads in the next line 
    index = index + 1; % increments index
end

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Ran the code and it seems to work, but I'm a complete MATLAB noob. Could you explain what each line/function does so that I can understand it better?

Comment: Sure.  I've added comments.

Comment: Awesome. Is there any way to access the nth element of a row/array? If I try and do data{4}{3} I get an error.

Comment: I made a correction to the first line of the while loop so the cell array data will contain integers, not string.  To access the third elements in the second line use data{1,2}(1,3).  {} to access the cell array, () to access the vector it contains.

Comment: What does the 1 in the brackets represent?

Comment: {rows,columns}. (rows,columns). The row is always one in this case and could actually be left out: data{2}(3).

Answer (score 0):

If you know your data will have the specific format of 5 numbers followed by a single number, you can use dlmread and then format the resulting matrix.

```
data = dlmread('data.txt',' ');
multipleValueRows = data(1:2:end,:);
singleValueRows = data(2:2:end,1);
```

The data matrix has the size (number of rows of your file) x 5 columns. In the rows where you only have a single number, the data matrix will contain zeros in columns 2-5.

Comment: Tested this code and I get a big matrix. How would I be able to compare an individual row, say the 4th row, to an array that I have? I can't seem to isolate only a row instead of say all the singleValueRows.

Comment: To access the 4th row > singleValuesRows(4). If you provide more details about your comparison data, I can give more specific comments.

Comment: Oh, okay. I was using {} instead of (). My comparrison data is an array of 5 numbers, so something like [1 1 2 3 4]. Need to compare my set to the row from your matrix. Was planning on using ismember to compare, unless you know of a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by compare? What do you need to know?

Comment: Need to know if my set matches the row. If not, need to know which elements are different.

Comment: I'm going to be sorting my set from least to biggest, and the "rules" that I'm parsing will be in order as well.

Comment: ismember may work. This will check to see if elements in comparison data are also in elements in data file. In that case, you wouldn't need to do any sorting. Alternatively, if you are checking to see if the elements at position 1,2... are equal, then use == operator.